# Files served from Apache are slower than other methods

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, performance

I have a vps with a 1Gb/s line, when running apps on the server I can get (be it not full) reasonable speeds, but when downloading files through apache from this server I never reach close to my line speed usually 600kb/s where I know the line should be able to comfortably do 1MB/s and more. What can I do to increase the download speeds.

Is there maybe a freeware or opensource php script that will increase my speeds?

Note. I have confirmed that my server can upload at more than 1MB/s, also that I can download at 1MB/s or more. Also I want to increase the speeds without a download accelerator.

Comment: Profile the apps, this almost certainly has nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: Please mention the speed you get as well, not just the speed you expect.

Comment: You need to be specific about what and how you are testing.  With performance metrics, details are very important.  The testing strategy, hosting platform, network status and server status can all significantly impact results.

Answer (score 1):

I would check whether changing the [EnableSendfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) setting makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider testing with an alternative web server such as http://nginx.com/ which is particularly fast at serving static files.